# How to Clear cached UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So, I've been implementing Automated testing for my iOS app and I've come across a strange issue.

With the testing framework I'm using (Frank), it attempts to Touch views/buttons/everything based on Accessibility labels. This works great, except for with `UITableViews` because of how they cache and reuse `UITableViewCells`. If I "delete" a cell from the table, the table caching system will flip the cell to Hidden. But it will still be there waiting to be reused, and my framework can still see it, which is causing issues.

So, **Question**: How can I force a UITableView to release all deleted/cached cells so they will no longer be part of the View hierarchy?

Comment: Even if you could do that, wouldn't you be testing what doesn't happen under real use?  doesn't it seem better to find a way for the testing system to know it's a deleted cell?

Comment: I would love to, but the testing system is a pre-compiled library so I can't make it ignore hidden objects like real user would.

Comment: what about in the tests themselves as opposed to the system?  can you check a hidden property?  Not directly familiar with Frank testing system ...

Answer (score 3):

This trick might help:

```
while([tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId]!=nil);
```

Of course, it needs manually repeat it for every possible `cellId`.
Note, cached cells is not a part of view hierarchy.

One more option. If `UITableViewController` is not currently visible, then invocation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method releases all its `UITableViewCell`s.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, use this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`
```

then check if your cell is nil. If it is, allocate a new instance of the cell.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell setDelegate:self];
}
```